# NVIDIA graphic card not showing even after installing additional drivers

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, vga

I followed all the steps as given on [linuxbabe.com](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04). The driver got installed successfully as shown in software and updates:
[software and updates (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pXtI.png) however in the about, graphics is still showing intel not nvidia [about not showing nvidia(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvwfi.png) **How to make my graphic card work in ubuntu?**

here is the output of lspci command on my system:[lspci terminal(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/341i0.png)
in VGA it is still showing intel. only 3D controller is showing the nvidia graphic card.

output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`: [lspci -k grep's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6qQS.png)

- ubuntu version: 18.04.3 LTS
- laptop: lenovo ideapad 520
- graphic card:    NVIDIA GeForce MX150

Comment: @Terrance it says `Info: the nvidia profile is already set` but about is showing intel not nvidia graphic card

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Terrance `prime-select query` shows `nvidia` and then when I do `prime-select nvidia` it shows that message. I have rebooted the computer.

Comment: It doesn't really mater what "about" is showing.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS. Nvidia module is not loading.

Comment: @Pilot6 i have added the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`. the VGA is still showing intel UHD graphics 620 ,and 3D controller is showing nvidia. but shouldn't both show nvidia?

Comment: @Pilot6 i disabled secure boot in BIOS and it worked!, thank you so much!. about is showing nvidia graphic card now.

Comment: @Pilot6 I always forget about Secure Boot in BIOS.  I swear it is the bane of my existence!  =)  Good thing you caught on to it!  =)

Comment: If you see that some module is there but not in use, most likely it's because of SB.